# making system call from 32-bit assembly in mac os x failed

Tags: macos, assembly, system-calls, 32-bit

I try to write a short 32-bit assembly program to test system calls in mac os x.

I write the first version which shows below, calling the write() function to print a string on the screen. it does work.

```
.data
str:
    .ascii  "Hello World\n"

.text
.globl  _main
_main:
    pushl   $12
    pushl   $str                
    pushl   $1                  
    movl    $4, %eax            
    subl    $4, %esp            
    int     $0x80               
    addl    $16, %esp          
    pushl   $0                  
    movl    $1, %eax            
    subl    $12, %esp           
    int     $0x80
```

After this, I decide to write another version uses mkdir() to make a new directory in "/tmp", but I failed. The system call number of mkdir() is 0x88 and my code shows below. Can anyone tell me where i am wrong. thanks very much.

```
.data
path:
    .ascii "/tmp/new_dir"

.text
.globl _main
_main:
    nop
    pushl   $path
    pushl   $0x1ff
    movl    $0x88, %eax
    subl    $8, %esp
    int     $0x80
    addl    $16, %esp

    pushl   $0                 
    movl    $1, %eax            
    subl    $12, %esp          
    int     $0x80
```

Comment: OS X needs stack to be 16-bytes aligned. I have already pushed 8-bytes. so, I need `subl $8` to align the stack.

Comment: Stack alignment has to happen *before* you push arguments. Otherwise, how could the callee know where to find the arguments? See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367494/understanding-osx-16-byte-alignment/21371636#21371636) for more about what's going on.

Comment: yes, you're right. alignment should be put before push argument. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://rudamoura.com/porting-asm.html) I found a simple guide for syscalls on MacOS. From what I read I assume that value of `%eax` register is the only one passed to syscall by register. The rest of registers must be pushed on the stack starting with `EDX`.

```
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Register |          Use           |            Location            |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
| EAX      | Unused, just a padding | [ESP]                          |
| EBX      | Name of directory      | [ESP+4]                        |
| ECX      | Access                 | [ESP+8]                        |
| EDX      | Unused                 | Unused, but let's say [ESP+12] |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

According to this table, your `mkdir` call should look like this:

```
pushl $0        /* for EDX, unused */
pushl $0x1FF    /* for ECX */
pushl $path /* for EBX */
movl $0x88, %eax
pushl %eax     /* for EAX but unused */
int $0x80
addl $16, %esp  /* clean up */
```

Adding on, your `exit` call doesn't seem to be OK either (I'm not sure, I'm not very familiar with this way of syscall-ing)

```
subl %esp, $8 /* unused EDX and ECX */
pushl $0      /* for EBX */
movl $1, %eax
pushl %eax    /* unused EAX */
int 0x80
```

**EDIT:** 
After digging up some materials on the topic of BSD syscalls, I also found a source recommending having the stack 16-byte aligned. This means that when you call a syscall with less then 4 parameters, you should push additional doublewords, and when you call a syscall with 5 or full 6 parameters, you should also push some doublewords for (if free) `ESI`, `EBP` and `ESP`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wonder how to deal with more than six parameters? Some book said that if more than six parameters required, the `%ebx` register is used to contain a pointer to the memory location of the input parameters, stored in sequential order. Could you show me an example which handles more than six parameters.

Comment: As far as I got, specific system calls have usually own formats for additional parameters. Which syscall are you interested in?

Comment: I haven't ever read the 32 bit abi, but I assume that you use some number of general purpose registers, then the rest go on the stack. at least that is what the 64bit abi specifies

Comment: No, x86 and x86-64 syscall calling conventions are different. xyzBSD uses the non-unix way of passing syscall parameters to sycall procedures by default. There is a way to change it (`brandelf`), though.

Comment: Your table is very confusing.  32-bit BSD / MacOS system calls don't care about registers other than EAX = call number.  I think that table is for porting Linux system calls, but nothing in the question is trying to use registers so you're just introducing that out of nowhere, making it look like registers matter.  And no, you don't have to push EAX.  In a normal BSD system-call wrapper function (in libc), that stack slot holds a return address, so the wrapper function can just use `int $0x80` with args where the function-calling convention put them.

Comment: [Assembly Linux system calls vs assembly OS x system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33194207) compares the two.