# Assembly Linux system calls vs assembly OS x system calls

Tags: linux, macos, assembly, x86, 32-bit

I have a problem with running assembly code on my mac. I am currently going through Jeff Duntemann's book Assembly Step by Step. The problem is that it focuses on writing assembly for 32 bit linux systems. I am using a 64 bit mac os x system. I can still run 32 bit assembly on my 64 bit system using nasm -f macho32, but apparently the code from Duntemann's book does not work because the system calls in Linux and mac os x are different. How would I convert this program:

```
;  Executable name : EATSYSCALL
;  Version         : 1.0
;  Created date    : 1/7/2009
;  Last update     : 2/18/2009
;  Author          : Jeff Duntemann
;  Description     : A simple program in assembly for Linux, using NASM 2.05,
;    demonstrating the use of Linux INT 80H syscalls to display text.
;
;  Build using these commands:
;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
;    ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
;

 SECTION .data          ; Section containing initialised data

     EatMsg: db "Eat at Joe's!",10
     EatLen: equ $-EatMsg   

 SECTION .bss           ; Section containing uninitialized data 

 SECTION .text          ; Section containing code

 global     _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

_start:
     nop            ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...
     mov eax,4      ; Specify sys_write call
     mov ebx,1      ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
     mov ecx,EatMsg     ; Pass offset of the message
     mov edx,EatLen     ; Pass the length of the message
     int 80H            ; Make kernel call

     mov eax,1      ; Code for Exit Syscall
     mov ebx,0      ; Return a code of zero 
     int 80H            ; Make kernel call
```

so that it would run on my mac os x system? I would prefer a solution that in 32 bit assembly because I am trying to learn that instead of 64 bit assembly which is much more complicated.

I have found a solution online, but it uses the stack and has other differences such as subtracting from the esp register even though Duntemann's program doesn't reference the esp register at all:

```
global start

 section .text
 start:
    push    dword msg.len
       push    dword msg
    push    dword 1
    mov     eax, 4
    sub     esp, 4
    int     0x80
    add     esp, 16

    push    dword 0
    mov     eax, 1
    sub     esp, 12
    int     0x80

 section .data

 msg:    db      "Hello, world!", 10
.len:   equ     $ - msg
```

So I guess what I want to know is a step by step process of how to convert a linux system call to a mac os x system call? That way as I'm going through this book I can just do that instead of having to download linux on a virtual machine or something.

Comment: As I noted in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116405/run-32-bit-assembly-on-64-bit-processor-with-mac-os-x), Mac OS X system calls are not an publicly documented interface. Use a 32-bit Linux system for this tutorial. (In a virtual machine, for instance.)

Comment: You should build with `nasm -f elf -o asmfile.o asmfile.asm` and link with `ld -m elf_i386 -o progname asmfile.o` for linux if building x86 on x86_64 (you can try on the mac, but as noted above -- no guarantees). As for the syscall numbers, linux has `unistd_32.h` (or potentially just `unistd.h` if it is just 32-bit). Usually found in `/usr/include/asm`,  `/usr/include/asm-x86`. If there is no publicly documented interface, there may be nothing similar on your mac. That file contains all syscall numbers on linux (32-bit) systems.

Comment: Also, if you notice, your two versions are doing the exact same thing and using the exact same syscalls `4-syswrite, 1-exit`.  The only difference appears that the mac version is filling `ebx, ecx & edx` with values pushed onto the stack for the `syswrite` call, and then pushing `0` (the exit status) onto the stack instead of loading `ebx` directly with it  before calling `exit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That solution is wrong. The line `sub esp, 12` should be `sub esp, 4`. It's not passing 0 as the exit status; it's passing a garbage value.

Mac OS X has BSD system calls. Examples are hard to find, because most programs for BSD don't make direct system calls; they link to libc and call functions in libc that wrap the system calls. But in assembly language, direct system calls can be simpler than libc calls.

For 32-bit Intel code, OS X and Linux both respond to `int 0x80`. They both take the system call number in `eax`, and they both return the result in `eax`. The major differences are these:

- Linux takes the arguments in registers (`ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`), but OS X takes the arguments on the stack. You push the arguments in reverse order, then push an extra 4 bytes.
- When an error happens, Linux puts a negative number in `eax`, but OS X puts a positive number in `eax`. OS X also sets a condition code so `jb` or `jnb` would jump if an error did or did not happen.
- The system calls have different numbers, and some have different arguments.

### Important file: [syscalls.master](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.25.20/bsd/kern/syscalls.master)

BSD systems use a file named syscalls.master to define system calls. I have linked to [syscalls.master from Mac OS X 10.4.11x86](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.25.20/bsd/kern/syscalls.master). We can use it to find the name, arguments, and return type for each system call. For example:

```
4   PRE     NONE    ALL { user_ssize_t write(int fd, user_addr_t cbuf, user_size_t nbyte); }
```

The write(2) system call is number 4, so we load `eax` with 4. It has 3 arguments, so we push them in reverse order: we push the number of bytes in the buffer, then push a pointer to the buffer, then push the file descriptor. After pushing the arguments, we push 4 extra bytes, perhaps with `sub esp, 4`. Then we do `int 0x80`. Then we probably want to `add esp, 16` to remove what we pushed.

Most arguments and return values are 4-byte integers, but `off_t` in OS X is always an 8-byte integer. We must be careful with calls like lseek(2).

```
199 NONE    NONE    ALL { off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence); }
```

The offset argument is an 8-byte integer, so we push it as a pair of 4-byte double-words. Intel processors are little-endian, and the stack grows down, so we push the high dword before pushing the low dword. The return type of lseek(2) is also an off_t. It comes in registers `eax` and `edx`, with the low word in `eax` and the high word in `edx`.

Some system calls are strange. To catch a signal, OS X has no system call for signal(3), unlike Linux. We must use sigaction(2), but it's strange:

```
46  NONE    KERN    ALL { int sigaction(int signum, struct __sigaction *nsa, struct sigaction *osa); }
```

The second argument isn't a regular sigaction struct. It's a bigger struct that includes an extra field for a trampoline. If we don't call sigaction() in libc, then we must [provide our own trampoline](https://github.com/kernigh/ack/blob/kernigh-osx/plat/osx386/libsys/sigaction.s)! It's different from Linux and from other BSD kernels.

Comment: `jc` / `jnc` more directly expresses the semantic meaning of testing CF to determine error or not.  (Synonym for `jb`, same opcode, but different meaning for humans.)